# How to send JWT token to Cookie and use in another routes?

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, jwt, express-jwt

**This is my Login Controller(JWT)**

```
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, secret);
res.header('auth-token', token).redirect('/home');
```

**This is my Middleware for JWT Token**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next)=>{
    const token = req.header('auth-token');
    if(!token){
        return res.send('Denied');
    }
    try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, secret);
        req.user = verified;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('JWT Error', error)
    }
}
```

**This is my Route Code**

```
const verify = require('../middlewares/tokenMiddleware');
router.get('/home', verify, (req, res, next)=>{
  res.render('home');
});
```

A token is assigning and can visible on the login route. But I want to send it to a cookie so that I can use it on all routes for user auth.

Comment: `res.header('auth-token', token).redirect('/home');` I'm not sure how this one worked. I thought that you can't set a header on a redirect because the redirect issues a new HTTP Request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the cookie parser package to set and read cookies from a request.
Reference : [Express (Cookie Parser)](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie)
After installing the package you can simply use it inside your node application.
Setting cookies :-

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(cookieParser());
res.cookie('auth-token', token, [options]);    // You can look up the options at the API reference
```

Reading cookies :-

```
const token = req.cookies['auth-token'];
```

As an alternative, to set cookies without using the cookie parser package, you have to use the `'Set-Cookie :`  header in order to set cookies using an HTTP header.

Comment: Just to be more specific: as of today, cookie-parser is **not** required in order to set cookies, but only to read cookies. Express.js Response entity already provides the ability to set cookies (see: [res.cookie()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie))